# PHP/HTML - Table Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, html-table

Currently I have a table that's linked to a MySQL Database and it get's the rows from the database.

It works perfectly and the arrays are displayed fine.

But instead of a normal table showing it down one each time, it's showing it side by side like below.

[image: Table Display]

The Player Names are blanked out due to privacy. But the blanked out spaces are where the Player is.

Here is the database connect file:

```
<?php
// MySQL Connection Details
$mysql_host = ""; // Host name 
$mysql_username = ""; // Mysql username 
$mysql_password = ""; // Mysql password 
$mysql_database = ""; // Database name 
$mysql_table = ""; // Table name 

// MySQL Connection
$con = mysqli_connect("$mysql_host","$mysql_username","$mysql_password","$mysql_database");

// MySQL Error Logging
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "MySQL Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $mysql_table";
$result = $con->query($sql);  

?>
```

Below is how it's displayed in the main php file.

```
<table id="ldr_table">
    <tr class="lb_tb_hd" align="center">
        <td>Player</td>
        <td>Points</td>
        <td>Wins</td>
        <td>Kills</td>
        <td>Deaths</td>
        <td>Played</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ldr_alt">
        <?php
        require('{db connection file}');
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH))
        {   
        echo '<td><center>' . $row['player_name'] . '</center></td>';
        echo '<td><center>' . $row['score'] . '</center></td>';
        echo '<td><center>' . $row['games_won'] . '</center></td>';
        echo '<td><center>' . $row['kills'] . '</center></td>';
        echo '<td><center>' . $row['deaths'] . '</center></td>';
        echo '<td><center>' . $row['games_played'] . '</center></td>';
        }
        mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've tried several things including `foreach` which had no effect on the format.

If there are other files needed I'll happily show them here.

Comment: Shouldnt your tr be instead your while so you get a able row with all your data for a retruend row, then close the table row, then go throug hthe while loop again ?

Comment: You don't need to put quote marks around your variables, such as `$mysql_host`, unless you intend to add text with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new row for each SQL result

```
<?php
require('{db connection file}');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
     echo '<tr class="ldr_alt">';
     echo '<td><center>' . $row['player_name'] . '</center></td>';
     echo '<td><center>' . $row['score'] . '</center></td>';
     echo '<td><center>' . $row['games_won'] . '</center></td>';
     echo '<td><center>' . $row['kills'] . '</center></td>';
     echo '<td><center>' . $row['deaths'] . '</center></td>';
     echo '<td><center>' . $row['games_played'] . '</center></td>';
     echo '</tr>';
}
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

**PS:**  use

```
text-align: center;
```

Instead of multiple center balise.

Answer (score 0):

Echo `<tr>` tag inside while loop.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
    echo '<tr class="ldr_alt">';
    echo '<td><center>' . $row['player_name'] . '</center></td>';
    echo '<td><center>' . $row['score'] . '</center></td>';
    echo '<td><center>' . $row['games_won'] . '</center></td>';
    echo '<td><center>' . $row['kills'] . '</center></td>';
    echo '<td><center>' . $row['deaths'] . '</center></td>';
    echo '<td><center>' . $row['games_played'] . '</center></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.Place `<tr>` tag within while loop

```
<table id="ldr_table">
        <tr class="lb_tb_hd" align="center">
            <td>Player</td>
            <td>Points</td>
            <td>Wins</td>
            <td>Kills</td>
            <td>Deaths</td>
            <td>Played</td>
        </tr>

            <?php
            require('{db connection file}');
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH))
            {   
            echo '<tr class="ldr_alt">'
            echo '<td><center>' . $row['player_name'] . '</center></td>';
            echo '<td><center>' . $row['score'] . '</center></td>';
            echo '<td><center>' . $row['games_won'] . '</center></td>';
            echo '<td><center>' . $row['kills'] . '</center></td>';
            echo '<td><center>' . $row['deaths'] . '</center></td>';
            echo '<td><center>' . $row['games_played'] . '</center></td>';
            echo '</tr>'
            }
            mysqli_close($con);
            ?>

    </table>
```